# How can i transform measure value to text message conditionally in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure in a table:

```
Item Count = DISTINCTCOUNT(Shoes[Item Name])
```

I want to display a text message in a new column, just like in the example below:

```
SingleOrMultiItem = IF([Item Count]>1, "Multiple", "Single")
```

I have tried to use the IF in a measure, and a column, but it won't work. It is said that `IF` will not work in slice (in the context)

ideas?

Comment: How does it not work? What is the result you get and what is the result you expect?

Comment: Can you show or give an example of your DataSet to better help you?

Comment: It turned out that there are some null values in the table and they affect the result. When they are removed, it is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example you can try this next formula to obain your message  in a new column:

NewColumn = IF(CALCULATE(SUMX(Shoes;Shoes[Item Count]))>1;"Multiple";"Single")

Please let me know if it works for you!